# Javascript Function not called onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

```
 <body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">LifeApp</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>

    <center><div class="card" id="life"><h3>20</h3></div></center>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button" onclick="incdec('-1')">-1</a><!-----------this function call----->
        <a class="button">+1</a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button">-5</a>
        <a class="button">+5</a>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button">Roll Dice</a>
        <a class="button">0</a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <center><a class="button">Reset</a></center>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
<script>
    function = incdec(plusminus){
        alert('running');
        plusminus = parseInt(plusminus);
        currentlife = document.getElementById("life").innerHTML + plusminus;
        document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = currentlife;
    }
</script>
```

I was trying to copy a video on youtube and while doing that the function incdec() is not getting called ..i tried everything but nothing seems to work

Comment: `function = incdec(plusminus)`? `=`? Is that a typo?

Comment: typo ? sorry i ddnt understand

Comment: `function = incdec(plusminus)` is a syntax error. Hence the question whether `=` is in your actual code or if it's just a typo in the question. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). I also recommend to change the call to `incdec(-1)` and remove the `plusminus = parseInt(plusminus);` part. If you want a number then just pass a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one syntax error, it's `function = incdec(plusminus)`. Change that to `function incdec(plusminus)`.

```
    <script>
        function incdec(plusminus){
            alert('running');
            plusminus = parseInt(plusminus);
            currentlife = document.getElementById("life").innerHTML + plusminus;
            document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = currentlife;
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: can u post the code please ?(just that part)..edit:-ah got it thank you :)))

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar...pls check my answer(updated), i get alert running and now everything works fine :) vote up if u r happy